# Can Swagger support Protobuf or WebSockets?

Tags: websocket, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, swagger, swagger-ui

I want my Swagger output to have support for Protobuf and Websockets.  (Protobuf is the most important)

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/146), I don't think that swagger can support that.  My goal is to allow end users to see the value of the Protobuf format since they are all asking me to use JSON instead.

I would contribute myself, but I'm unfamiliar with the swagger project at that level.

**Question**

Is there any way to get Swagger to support Protobuf or WebSockets?

Comment: I've been investigating a similar issue, and this is about as close as I've gotten to what I believe you're asking for:
https://coreos.com/blog/gRPC-protobufs-swagger.html

This uses a gRPC REST gateway (to a gRPC server) on the server end.  According to this:
https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/124
the gateway can support serialized protobufs as a content-type.  I don't think this is quite what you're asking, as the swagger definition will still be JSON, but thought I'd pass along